# how to read a xml file and write into list then get the path for txt file and read it

Tags: c#, xml

I am having a xml file.this having the path for my log file(txt).This xml file having some modules and each having the log file path.so i want to read the xml and list the details of each module then i want to read the txt file(using the path).can anyone please give some idea to do this stuff.

Thanks,
This is my xml file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <Modules>    
    <ServiceHost>
     <LogType value="FatalErrorLog">
     <Fields>
      <FileName>ServiceWS.log</FileName>
      <FileLocation>\\10.8.8.21\lv0\Logs\Prod\Service\</FileLocation>
      <IsLogFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDateFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDownloadRawFile value="false" />
    </Fields>
  </LogType>
   <LogType value="DebugLog">
     <Fields>
      <FileName>ServiceDebugWS.log</FileName>
      <FileLocation>\\10.8.8.21\lv0\Logs\Prod\ServiceHost</FileLocation>
      <IsLogFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDateFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDownloadRawFile value="false" />
    </Fields>
  </LogType>
</ServiceHost>
<Product value="Debug">
   <LogType>
     <Fields>
      <FileName>Product.log</FileName>
      <FileLocation>\\10.8.8.21\lv0\Logs\Prod\Endor\</FileLocation>
      <IsLogFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDateFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDownloadRawFile value="false" />
    </Fields>
  </LogType>
</Product>
<Portal value="Debug">
   <LogType>
     <Fields>
      <FileName>Portal.log</FileName>
      <FileLocation>\\10.8.8.21\lv0\Logs\Prod\SupportPortal\</FileLocation>
      <IsLogFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDateFilterAvailable value="true" />
      <IsDownloadRawFile value="false" />
    </Fields>
  </LogType>
</Portal>
<Modules>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i could read the xml and list it.how to get the txt file from the path.

Comment: `string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);`

Comment: @Damith, thanks i could read the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
XmlDocument xml_Document = new XmlDocument();
xml_Document.Load("C:\\settings.xml");
var list = xml_Document.SelectNodes("//LogType [@value='Debug']");
var logLocation = list.Item(0).SelectNodes("//FileLocation").Item(0).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks,its really helped a lot.i have one more question like if the file is in another server?

Comment: The Load function is very handy. It can load from a url too. Refer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REGEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)to find the anything in the xml file. Suppose you want to get the txt file names in an array then you can do it by following......

```
// get the string start with <FileLocation> and end with </FileLocation> 
MatchCollection v = Regex.Matches(input_string, "<FileLocation>(.)*</FileLocation>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            string[] arr=new string[total_length];
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (Match i in v)
            {

                string s = i.Value;
                s= s.Replace("<FileLocation>", "");
                s=s.Replace("</FileLocation>","");
                arr[counter] = s;
                counter++;

            }
```

You can find and extract any string in this way.

Then you can use the arr array to open txt file or do what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XmlDocument as point **nunespascal** either use XPath, which is more comfortable (though rather similar to Xml)

```
        XPathDocument xdoc = new XPathDocument(filename);
        XPathNavigator xnav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
        // path in XML to file location
        XPathNodeIterator xiter = xnav.Select("/Modules/ServiceHost/LogType/Fields/FileLocation");
        foreach(var item in xiter)
        {
            Log(item.ToString());
        }
```

P.S.  in your XML file is not closed :)